# Copy files from root folder of android to pc using python

Tags: python, sqlite, adb, data-recovery

....I am working on a project where I need to copy some files of an app that is present in the rooted folder of android. I need to write a python script that can help to get the required files from root folder of android to p. The dives I am using is already rooted.

I try to do it by adb but android not grant SU premmsions to a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH9WV.png)

Comment: Have you ever tried using `adb root` then `adb shell` and your commands?

Comment: if `su` gives "permission denied" you have not granted superuser permissions in the root management app to shell/adb (e.g. magisk app). Note that on modern devices with root partition (not a system permission) it is no longer possible to modify this partition, even with root permissions).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.